# Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$

Tags: measure-theory

Is $A=\{(x_n)\in \mathbb{R^\infty}:\limsup_n x_n=\liminf_nx_n\}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$?

I think it is true because $A$ equals

$$
\left\{(x_n)\in \mathbb{R^\infty}:\bigcap_{k\ge 1}|\limsup_n x_n-\liminf_nx_n|\le k^{-1}\right\}.
$$